# Hide image in PDF, reveal with mouseover

Tags: graphics, pdftex

Is there a way to load a hidden image into a pdf output document that will show up when the user moves the cursor over a relevant piece of text?

E.g., a pdf file generated by tex contains

> **this arbitrary block of text**

and when you move your cursor over it, a picture appears near the cursor.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`fancytooltips`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancytooltips); this requires Acrobat Reader to work. A little example:

Create a file `image.tex` like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[createtips]{fancytooltips}

\begin{document}

\keytip{a}{\includegraphics[height=4cm]{example-image-a}}
\clearpage

\end{document}
```

process this file to get a file `image.pdf`. In the same folder, create another file (the "main" file), like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[filename=image,mouseover,noextratext,movetips]{fancytooltips}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\begin{document}

\lipsum[4]
\tooltip{this is the designated text}{a}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

The string used for `filename` has to be the same as the name of the pdf file containing the tooltip. Process this document; when you hover over `this is the designated text` the image will appear in a tooltip.

An image of the resulting PDF file with the cursor away from the designated text:

[image]

and an image once the cursor hovers over the text:

[image]