# latex to html with collapsing

Tags: html

Is there a solution to this

[fold/unfold sections to expand in PDF](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171898/fold-unfold-sections-to-expand-in-pdf)

in terms of HTML? In other words, can I compile to HTML and have certain parts of my work collapsed?

So for instance, I would want something like this

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{thm}
blah blah blah
\end{thm}
\begin{collapse}
\begin{proof}
  First step is true.
  \begin{collapse}
  First step is true because blah blah blah. 
  \end{collapse}
  Second step is true.
  Final step is true. 
\end{proof}
\end{collapse}

\end{document}
```

to generate HTML where I can click on something to expand the proof and also click on something else to expand the details. It would be nice if the word "Proof" just appeared as a link. I'm trying to find simple CSS that does this. And the collapse environment should accept an argument on what text to make into a link.

Here is the HTML/CSS/JS:

http://cssdeck.com/labs/vx3fpxc0

(I have no idea if the code in that link is correct. I just modified somebody else's so that it works.)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What is the problem with doing it manually and how should a converter know which parts to collapse?

Comment: this needs to be done using CSS and JavaScript, so any converter which can include custom CSS and JavaScript to the converted document can do the job. I am sure `tex4ht` can do this. We need a sample document and more concrete specification what should be collapsed, then it will be possible to provide a concrete solution.

Comment: @TeXnician I was thinking you wrap the thing you want collapsed within an environment, like [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11177/how-to-write-hidden-notes-in-a-latex-file/11179). This could be a comment, a proof, or details of a proof you want to omit. What do you mean by manually? I think this has the benefit of working across more platforms. (The PDF collapsing doesn't work in all viewers.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a solution using `tex4ht`. I've modified your example slightly to provide definitions for `thm` and collapse environments:

```
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/467746/2891
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}


\newenvironment{collapse}{}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{thm}
blah blah blah
\end{thm}
\begin{collapse}
\begin{proof}
  First step is true.
  \begin{collapse}
  First step is true because blah blah blah. 
  \end{collapse}
  Second step is true.
  Final step is true. 
\end{proof}
\end{collapse}

\end{document}
```

The JavaScript code should be put in the `collapse.js` file:

```javascript
$('[data-toggle]').on('click', function(){
  var id = $(this).data("toggle"),
      $object = $("#" +  id),
      className = "collapse";

  if ($object) {
    if ($object.hasClass(className)) {
      $object.removeClass(className)
      $(this).text("Collapse");
    } else {
      $object.addClass(className)
      $(this).text("Expand");
    }
  }
});
```

Lastly, we must configure `tex4ht` to include all the JavaScript and to produce a usable code for the `collapse` environment. Put the following code in the `myconfig.cfg` file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\newcounter{collapseid}
\ConfigureEnv{collapse}{%
\stepcounter{collapseid}
\edef\currentid{collapse-\arabic{collapseid}}
\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<div  class="collapse-label"><a data-toggle="\currentid" href="\#">Expand</a></div>\Hnewline<div id="\currentid" class="collapse">}%
\par
}
{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{</div>}\par}{}{}
\Css{.collapse{display:none;}}
\Css{.open{display:block;}}
\Configure{@/BODY}{\HCode{<script class="cssdeck" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>}}
\Configure{@/BODY}{\HCode{<script type="text/javascript" src="collapse.js"></script>}}

\begin{document}

\EndPreamble
```

The `\ConfigureEnv{collapse}` command configures HTML code inserted to the document. It also produces unique `id` attribute for each of the collapsed environments and handles paragraph endings. The `\Css` command is used for the necessary CSS configurations and the `\Configure{@/BODY}` commands are used to insert the requests for the Java Script files at the end of the page.

The document can be compiled using the following commnad:

```
make4ht -c myconfig.cfg filename.tex
```

This is the result (without the HTML header):

```xml
   <div class="newtheorem">
<!--l. 12--><p class="noindent" ><span class="head">
<a 
 id="x1-2r1"></a>
<span 
class="cmbx-10">Theorem 1.</span>  </span><span 
class="cmti-10">blah blah blah</span>
</p>
   </div>
   <div class="collapse-label"><a data-toggle="collapse-1" href="#">Expand</a></div> 
<div id="collapse-1" class="collapse">
<!--l. 16--><p class="indent" >
</p>
   <div class="proof">
<!--l. 17--><p class="indent" >   <span class="head">
<span 
class="cmti-10">Proof.</span> </span>First step is true.   </p><div class="collapse-label"><a data-toggle="collapse-2" href="#">Expand</a></div> 
<div id="collapse-2" class="collapse">
<!--l. 19--><p class="indent" >   First step is true because blah blah blah.
</p></div>
<!--l. 21--><p class="indent" >   Second step is true. Final step is true.                                               □
</p>
   </div>
   </div>
   <script class="cssdeck" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="collapse.js"></script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

[Here is a interactive example](http://cssdeck.com/labs/full/zskpvlkz)