# Animated Proof PDF

Tags: animations, animate, movie15

This animation in wikipedia can be done with Latex in a pdf document? The problem is if it takes up vertical space, the text below has to scroll. Note that animation is unfold and not embed.

For example: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_law#Equivalence_of_integral_and_differential_forms)

[image]

Any hint, would be appreciated.

Comment: You can use `ocgx2` for that. It would really help if you could post a small sample document without these effects such that people do not have to start from scratch.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [fold/unfold sections to expand in PDF](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171898/fold-unfold-sections-to-expand-in-pdf)

Comment: The problem is if it takes up vertical space, the text below has to scroll.