# How to create a text only visible by mouse hovering over it

Tags: math-mode, fonts, equations

I have seen in numerous answers on MathStackexchange when the solution is displayed, it is blank and you need to hover your mouse over it for it to display.

However I searched for hours for an answer like that and somehow I could not find any. Does anybody know how to make such latex text?

Comment: That is probably a web/browser/javascript thing. Not really related to LaTeX and friends.

Comment: @daleif I really hoped that latex has a simillar feature...

Comment: I don't really see the point of having one? Especially in touch devices.

Comment: Have you looked at questions on this website [such as this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126426/hide-image-in-pdf-reveal-with-mouseover)? I believe there might be something you are looking for, but I think it will depend on the device and the PDF reader.

Comment: See, for example, this one https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/164186

Comment: The eforms package supports things like `\textField[\AA{\AAMouseEnter{%`  (\AA stands for Additional Actions).

Comment: If instead of a mouseover/hover you would be ok with a mouse click then you can consider the `ogcx` package (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/270780/spoiler-like-feature-in-output-pdf/270807 for example) or the newer `ocgx2` (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/432382/interactive-svg/447800).